# Reusing cdk.tf.json (inside cdktf.out) instead of generating new one each cdktf deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-cdk

I want to generate only one time that cdk.tf.json file using cdktf synth and each  time
i want to deploy i want to use that cdk.tf.json generated  when cdktf synth is executed.

So the workflow will look like very similar to:

```bash
terraform plan -out tfplan 
terraform apply tfplan
```

Comment: did you find a solution? If so it would be great to post it here :)

Comment: Why would you want to re-use it?

Comment: @DanielSchmidt  i think it will be useless to regenerate  the  json file at synth phase and  at deployment  phase, also for programming languages other  than typescript, generating the  json takes a  lot of time. thank you

Comment: @FlorianLudwig well did'nt find solution yet ,  but  i think you can generate the  json file using cdktf synth then you navigate to cdktf.out folder where the  JSON file exists then run Terrafrom Apply instead of CDKTF Deploy.

Comment: Does sth like this solve your problem? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/pull/2993

Comment: @DanielSchmidt   Adding it as an option in cdtkf deploy command  would be a great idea, thanks.